# where to put log4j.xml in netbeans 6.8?

Tags: log4j, netbeans6.8

In my case,
I have configured my log4j.xml like this.

```
<appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <errorHandler class="org.apache.log4j.helpers.OnlyOnceErrorHandler" />
        <param name="File" value="F:/myLogger.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="20000KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="400" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5l - %m%n%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

<!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="error" />

            <appender-ref ref="FILE" />

    </root>
```

and put log4.xml file in source package.
[image]

but logger file is not created at specified folder.Let me know the exact path.
(it may be tha t i am using some external JAR which may have log4j.xml) so how to give priority to root application log4j.xml file.